# Why are subsets of $\mathbb{Q}$ with non trivial interior are NOT compact?

Tags: general-topology

Consider $\mathbb{Q} \subset \mathbb{R}$ with the subspace topology. Show that for all $A \subset \mathbb{Q}$ with $A^\circ \neq \varnothing$, A is not compact. So far I've tried to take a covering of A and assume that there is a finite subcovering in order to arrive to a contradiction but this doesn't seem to work. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you use the following fact: for $K\subset Y\subset X$, $K$ is compact in $Y$ w.r.t. the subspace topology iff $K$ is compact in $X$. If you can use it, then try to show $A$ is not compact as a subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @JoeyZou But for example $[0,1]$ is compact in $\mathbb{R}$ but $[0,1]$ wouldn't be compact in $\mathbb{Q}$ because its interior is non-trivial.

Comment: Notice that $[0,1]$ is not a subset of $\mathbb{Q}$. If you meant $[0,1]\cap\mathbb{Q}$ instead, then it is a subset of $\mathbb{Q}$, but it is not compact, either in $\mathbb{Q}$ or in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: A compact space is complete.

Comment: Your thinking about the logic of this question isn't quite right. There will be lots of open coverings of $A$ that **do** have finite subcoverings. What you need to show is that there is **some** open covering that has no finite subcovering.

Answer (score 2):

As $A^{\circ} \neq \emptyset$, there is an open interval $X =  (a, b) \subseteq \Bbb{R}$ such that $X \cap \Bbb{Q} \subseteq A$. Pick $\xi$ in $X \setminus \Bbb{Q}$. Then the collection of all the sets $X_r = (\xi - r, \xi) \cup (\xi, \xi + r)\,$ for $r > 0$ covers $A$, but no finite collection of the $X_r$ covers $A$. So $A$ is not compact.

Comment: Did you mean $X_r = (-r,\xi) \cup (\xi,r)$? And why is there no finite collection of the $X_r$ that covers A?

Comment: I've fixed the definition of the $X_r$. No finite collection of the $X_r$ covers $A$, because $X \cap \Bbb{Q}$ is contained in $A$ and contains points arbitrarily close to $\xi$.